# Applying Search Filter results in 0 search results?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Search form works great.  The search filter which takes the search results and filters them some more works great EXCEPT when I use one specific filter which basically allows a person to find a school based on specific tuition price.

Tuition prices are inputted into the database in ranges.  For example: "20,000-30,000" would be what can be found in a column cell.  The column uses VARCHAR data type.

This is the code for that particular filter:

HTML

```
 <input name="fees" type="range" min="1" max="200000" value="" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

PHP

```
 ->where('fees', '<', '%'.$fees.'%')
```

If a person searches 10000, any school whose data for that field is LESS than 10000 should show up.

There are over 200 schools in the database but no matter what I search in the filter, 0 results show.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are using `<` and what I assume is a LIKE criteria. Are you getting a little mixed up?

Comment: The original code didn't work either.  The original code was: ->where('fees', 'LIKE', '%'.$fees.'%').  If you know the proper way of putting the < into the code, please share it.

Comment: "20,000-30,000" would be what can be found in a column cell. The column uses VARCHAR data type. ----- so you mean each cell has a string?

Comment: @HamzaMohamed I guess so if "20,000-30,000" is considered a string.  I'm not sure what the correct data type is.

Comment: seems so .. based on the max value, you got around 20 records, 10,000 is the data range between the high point and low point for each?

Comment: A typical data range between low and high would be 10,000-20,000.  Some schools have tuition have data of 20,000-35,000.  Others may have 40,000-65,000.  But still, if you put 15000 in the filter, you should not get 0 results, which is what I am getting.....no idea why.

Comment: @RiggsFolly any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add extra column in the database (which I doubt it) just add the least figure out of the data range and use the same query; just without %

`->where('feesNewCol', '<', $fees)`

if not, you can:

add a closure to your where query like the following:

```
->where(function ($query) use ($fees) {
            $schools = $query->pluck('feeRange', 'schoolName');
            foreach ($schools as $feeRange => $schoolName) {
                ((explode('-',$feeRange))[0] < $fees) ? echo $schoolName : Break;
            }

})
```

of course that is not a feasible solution as it has an if in a loop in a query, however that is due to the constraints.

## Another way from the front end

You can add a slider filter that will transfer the current figure to an option searchable in the VARCHAR column.

add a hidden input field in your html to receive the option number, which you will match in your database.

`<input type="hidden" value='' id='feesOptions'>`

```
<script>
var feesOptions = (document.getElementById("feesOptions").value; 
var fees = (document.getElementById("fees").value;
feesOptions = fees;
document.getElementById("fees").addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
fees != feesOptions ? myFunction(event) : false;
});

function myFunction(e) {
var x = 0;
switch (true) { // list all your options
case (x > 10000 && x =< 20000):
    x = '10,000-20,000';
    break;
case (x > 20000 && x =< 50000):
    x = '20,000-50,000';
    break;
}
    feesOptions = x;
}
</script>
```

finally, receive the feesOptions input and query with it.

Comment: what is the difference between "feesNewCol" and my current "fees" column?

Comment: if you can amend the database, it is going to save you lots of server performance and better code .. add a new column which is the lowest point in the data range .. e.g. 20,000-30,000 .. you add 20,000

Comment: Putting that into consideration, is it possible to make it work with the current string?  eg: 20,000-30,000

Comment: try the where query with the closure, hopefully it should work

Comment: I'm thinking if I will just do it the old fashioned way.  Do an input type that searches for text that contains specific characters instead of a range.  Some websites have that where you can search from one of a few options: 0-10,000, 10,000-20,000, 20,000-30,000, etc.  I don't want to have a loop in my search filter.

Comment: did you consider searching by options and range together? it is basically a JS filter on input and then update the value to match the options in the fees

Comment: I was under the impression that you cannot change anything but the backend code, but if you can change the front-end this opens a lot of options

Comment: I posted code from my front end.....the HTML.  That should have given you a clue that I can edit code in both frontend and backend....  I just have to figure out a way to modify the code.